# .htaccess redirect URL with loaded css, js and image

Tags: apache, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the URL from the .htaccess file, tried a lot but ended up with frustration.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond    ^suba/?$    resources/uploads/releases/zipfiles/1484883480/index\.html [NC, C]
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I just want to open [this](http://dittmagasin.no/resources/uploads/releases/zipfiles/1484883480/index.html) with the short URL like this to make it more SEO friendly,
http://dittmagasin.no/release.

I have referred to the following posts:

1. [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)
2. [URL rewriting for beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^release/?$ resources/uploads/releases/zipfiles/1484883480/index.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: http://dittmagasin.no/release, doesnt load the CSS, JS and Image. Could you help me with that please ?

Comment: You can notice the difference between http://dittmagasin.no/release and http://dittmagasin.no/resources/uploads/releases/zipfiles/1484883480/index.html

Comment: That is because of relative paths in your css/js/image. You need to add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/resources/uploads/releases/zipfiles/1484883480/" />`

Comment: As we generate(1484883480) automatically each time a release is uploaded to the system, do we have any solution without including this number?

Comment: If `1484883480` is generated dynamically then how come `css` folder is inside `1484883480` ?

Comment: As I have mentioned earlier that this folder name(zip file) is generated while uploading the magazine. `1484883480` is folder name and so it has `css`, `js` and `image` within this too.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier also that problem is with your use of relative paths. Rewrite rule part is done. It is up to you how you want to tell browser to find css/js/images. There are 2 solutions: you can either provide full path that starts with `/` or you can use `base` tag as I suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would try